# Bug report: Wrong position of the UIElement / ChartMarkerXY when first rendering a chart with animation disabled

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I've tried to place an [UIElement](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/chartxy.html#adduielement) / [ChartMarkerXY](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/classes/chartxy.html#addchartmarkerxy) on a chart where the animations are disabled.

Unfortunately, the UIElement / ChartMarkerXY was not in the right position on the first render.

However, when we do an another render (eg: when you put the mouse on the chart for show the AutoCursor), it has been moved to the right position.

I noticed that when the animations are enabled, the first frame of the animation put the UIElement / ChartMarkerXY at the same position.

Currently, I have a workaround for prevent this: [chart.engine.renderFrame(0,0)](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/publicengine.html#renderframe)

[Demonstration of the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR0OJ.gif)

You can find in the snippet an example that reproduce the bug:

```js
const {
  AxisPosition,
  AxisTickStrategies,
  emptyLine,
  lightningChart,
  Point,
  UIElementBuilders,
  emptyFill
} = lcjs;

const dataSeries = [
  { x: -5, y: 0 },
  { x: 2, y: -5 },
  { x: 5, y: 6 },
  { x: 8, y: 12 },
  { x: 12, y: -12 }
];

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
  container: 'chart',
});
chart.setAnimationsEnabled(false);
chart.addLineSeries().add(dataSeries);

chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, {
    x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
    y: chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  })
  .setText('My Text')
  .setPosition({ x: 0, y: 0 });
```

```css
.lcCanvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>

<h2>Example of the bug</h2>
<div id="chart" class="lcCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Bug reports should be sent to support@lightningchart.com instead of posting here.

Comment: @Snekw > Thank you for your answer. Should send a bug report on the support mail.  
I just let the question here, with the workaround, in case people have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bug reports should be sent to support@lightningchart.com instead of posting here.
> -- [Snekw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6198227/snekw)

Bug report sent.

Currently, the workaround I found is [chart.engine.renderFrame(0,0)](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.1.0/interfaces/publicengine.html#renderframe).
This will force the re-render of the chart, and put the marker at the right position.

Here, a snippet of how implement the workaround.

```js
const {
  AxisPosition,
  AxisTickStrategies,
  emptyLine,
  lightningChart,
  Point,
  UIElementBuilders,
  emptyFill
} = lcjs;

const dataSeries = [
  { x: -5, y: 0 },
  { x: 2, y: -5 },
  { x: 5, y: 6 },
  { x: 8, y: 12 },
  { x: 12, y: -12 }
];

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY({
  container: 'chart',
});
chart.setAnimationsEnabled(false);
chart.addLineSeries().add(dataSeries);

chart.addUIElement(UIElementBuilders.TextBox, {
    x: chart.getDefaultAxisX(),
    y: chart.getDefaultAxisY()
  })
  .setText('My Text')
  .setPosition({ x: 0, y: 0 });

chart.engine.renderFrame(0, 0); // Workaround: Add this for force the re-render
```

```css
.lcCanvas {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.1.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>

<h2>Workaround</h2>
<div id="chart" class="lcCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29534723)

Comment: @Matt > You are right. I have edited my answer accordingly.